# Replacing for my $i ( 0, 1, 2 ) with something more stylish?

Tags: perl

I usually write my Perl tests in this way

```
 for my $i ( 0, 1, 2 ) {
    is_deeply( $fetch_public_topic_ids->[$i],
 $expected_sorted_topic_list->[$i], 'Match' );
```

when `$expected_sorted_topic` is an array ref for my test case data. I sometimes get feedback that I should avoid writing 0, 1, 2, 3... or 0...5 in my "for", as it is considered "bad style"?

But what alternatives do I have instead?

Comment: thanks @TLP what does a C-style loop look like btw

Comment: Please avoid using the title to tag your posts, use the tagging system instead.

Comment: err, ask whoever is giving you that feedback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to iterate over the indexes of an array, but no array figures in the determining of the index. The problem is the hardcoding of the indexes.

```
for my $i (0..$#$fetch_public_topic_ids) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Why are you even using a loop at all?

You should just be able to do

```
is_deeply( $fetch_public_topic_ids, $expected_sorted_topic_list );
```

Comment: didn't know it was that deep

Answer (score 1):

Put your tests in an array of hashes:

```
my @tests = (
    {
        fetch_public_topic_ids     => [ "whatever" ],
        expected_sorted_topic_list => [ "whatever" ],
        test_name                  => "Match",
    },
    # repeat as needed
);

for my $test ( @tests ){
    is_deeply( $test->{ fetch_public_topic_ids     },
               $test->{ expected_sorted_topic_list },
               $test->{ test_name                  },
           );
}
```